# type error when compiling

Tags: haskell

I don't understand why the following code won't compile:

```
 append :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
 append xs ys = foldr (:) ys xs

 traverse :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
 traverse x [] = [[x]]
 traverse x (y:ys) = append [(x:y:ys)] (map (y:) (traverse x ys))

 comb :: [a] -> [[a]]
 comb [] = [[]]
 comb (x:[]) = [[x]]
 comb (x:y:[]) = [[x,y],[y,x]] 
 comb (x:xs) = map (traverse x) (comb xs)
```

It produces the following error:

```
pr27.hs:13:20:
Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
`a' is a rigid type variable bound by
the type signature for comb :: [a] -> [[a]] at pr27.hs:10:1
Expected type: [a] -> [a]
Actual type: [a] -> [[a]]
In the return type of a call of `traverse'
In the first argument of `map', namely `(traverse x)'
Failed, modules loaded: none
```

But when I load just `traverse` and use it in an expression similar to the above, I get the desired result.  What's going on?

```
Main> map (traverse 3) [[1,2],[2,1]]
     [[[3,1,2],[1,3,2],[1,2,3]],[[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[2,1,3]]]
```

Comment: Tikhon has explained the problem, so let me try to give the solution. Unless I'm badly mistaken, what you want would be achieved by changing the last equation of `comb` to `comb (x:xs) = concatMap (traverse x) (comb xs)` or `comb (x:xs) = comb xs >>= traverse x`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `comb` has to return a value of type `[[a]]`. `traverse` returns a value of type `[[a]]`, so mapping it over another list produces `[[[a]]]`, which has too many levels of nesting.

Let's look at `map`. It has a type `map :: (x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]`. `traverse x` has a type `[a] -> [[a]]`. Now we need to combine the two. To do this, we replace `x` with `[a]` and `y` with `[[a]]`, getting `([a] -> [[a]]) -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]`. This clearly shows the result of mapping `traverse` has to have at least three levels of nesting.

If you look at your example, this is what you actually get. For `comb`, you only want one two levels deep.

The reason your example worked in GHCi is because an expression there can have *any* type. Your `map (traverse 3) [[1,2], [2,1]]` expression is perfectly legal; however, it has the type `Num a => [[[a]]]`, which is a list of lists of lists of numbers. (Try it: `:t map (traverse 3) [[1,2], [2,3]]`.) However, the type of `comb` is `[a] -> [[a]]`. This means the result has to be a list of lists, not a list of lists of lists. So the issue is that `map (traverse 3)` is incompatible with `comb`, not that it is illegal by itself.

Comment: So why I can run the expression online at Perlude (?). Please view the bottom of my question . Thanks

Comment: At `Main`, you are passing the `map` something of type `[[a]]`, and getting back something of type `[[[a]]]`.  In the last line of `comb`, you are passing in (according to the type definition of `comb`) something of type `[[a]]`, so you will get back something of type `[[[a]]]`, which becomes the result of `comb`.  However, the result of `comb` is supposed to be `[[a]]`, not `[[[a]]]`.